# How to convert to String with DateTimeFormatter

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime-format

Now i have in my db date as Long:

```
val time = target?.date ?: 0L
```

And i convert it to Date:

```
val date = Date(time)
```

And after this use as String to display my date:

```
val format = SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM, yyyy")
format.format(date)
```

Everything works correctly

But now I want to do the same thing just using `DateTimeFormatter`
Is that possible?

Comment: `format.format(date)` returns that string

Comment: Are you intending to use the `DateTimeFormatter` class? The API is a bit different: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: @Edric yes, I took into the moment with the API but my problem is that I initially type Long. So i don't know how do I convert from long to string

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter` works with fx `LocalDate` is this a question how to convert `long` to `LocalDate` ?

Comment: @Selvin i updated question, hope now became more understandable

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this:

```
val shortFormat : DateTimeFormatter =
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yy").withZone(PST)
val formatted : String = shortFormat.print(time)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the docs for the [`DateTimeFormatter` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) before reading on. Anyways, you can use the `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` classes.

Looking at the [`LocalDate` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) documentation, I see that there's a way to allow specifying a long via the [`LocalDate#ofEpochDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofEpochDay-long-) method.

Anyways, there's a code sample in the `DateTimeFormatter` class documentation which I'll copy verbatim here, but adapted to use the `LocalDate#ofEpochDay` method:

```
val date = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(target?.date ?: 0L)
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM, yyyy")
val format = date.format(formatter)
```

Additionally, I've shortened the amount of code needed to solve your problem.

Hope this helps! (P.S. I have yet to test the code sample above as of now.)

Comment: get next error: `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeException: Invalid value for EpochDay (valid values -365243219162 - 365241780471): 1569715200000
`

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your `Date` object into `LocalDate` and from there it's straighforward. Here's a working example using the [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/xz3mbRvIi)

```
fun formatMillisUsingDateTimeFormatter(millis: Long): String {
    val date = Date(millis).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()

    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault())

    return date.format(formatter)
}
```

A `LocalDate` object has the [#format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) which gets directly the `DateTimeFormatter` to convert itself into a String. Now, to convert a `Date` object into a `LocalDate` object it involves several transformations and I would recommend against it, however you need to convert it into an [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), then [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) and finally to [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Comment: I use the library `implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1', 
` and don t understand why yours method need API 26...

Comment: Because java APIs are not available since Android API 1. You should check the android docs.

Answer (score 0):

As @edric mention, we can use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to format [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) ,

To conver long(ex milliseconds) to `LocalDate` we can use multiple ways.

```
val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd")
```

1. The first way(Ref : java.time.LocalDate#now(java.time.Clock) or org.threeten.bp.LocalDate#now(java.time.Clock))

   `LocalDate.ofEpochDay(Math.floorDiv(time, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).format(dateTimeFormatter)`

2nd and 3rd way we can use `Calendar`

2.

```
    var time = target?.date ?: 0L

    var calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeInMillis = time

    LocalDate.of(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    ).format(dateTimeFormatter)
```

3.

```
    var time = target?.date ?: 0L

    var calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeInMillis = time

    LocalDate.ofYearDay(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)).format(dateTimeFormatter)
```